# Why does this tutorial on reinforced learning not check whether the environment is 'game over' during training?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow, training, environment

I am following the tutorial [Train a Deep Q Network with TF-Agents](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial). It uses the `hello world` environment of reinforced learning: [cart pole](https://gym.openai.com/envs/CartPole-v0/).

At the end, the agent is getting trained with experience on the training enviroment (`train_env`). When performing an action in the environment a `time_step` is returned containing the observation, award and whether the environment signals the end, which basically says 'game over'. This can be due to the pole reaching an angle which is too high, or 200 time steps have been reached (which is the max score, atleast in the tutorial).

When `compute_avg_return` method evaluates an agents performance on an environment, the environment is checked to be game over or not using `time_step.is_last`.

Why is `time_step.is_last` not considered when training the agent at the end of the tutorial? Nor do I see that the environment is reset during training. Or at least, I do not see it in the code presented. Is it checked internally? Looking at the graph, it never goes over an average return (the score) of 200 time steps. So it does seem to check for `time_step.is_last`. Do I overlook something or how does this work?

See the code block below. I would expect the check for `time_step.is_last` after `collect_step(train_env, agent.collect_policy, replay_buffer)`, which would be followed by resetting the environment if it was true.

```
# Reset the train step
agent.train_step_counter.assign(0)

# Evaluate the agent's policy once before training.
avg_return = compute_avg_return(eval_env, agent.policy, num_eval_episodes)
returns = [avg_return]

for _ in range(num_iterations):

  # Collect a few steps using collect_policy and save to the replay buffer.
  for _ in range(collect_steps_per_iteration):
    collect_step(train_env, agent.collect_policy, replay_buffer)

  # Sample a batch of data from the buffer and update the agent's network.
  experience, unused_info = next(iterator)
  train_loss = agent.train(experience).loss

  step = agent.train_step_counter.numpy()

  if step % log_interval == 0:
    print('step = {0}: loss = {1}'.format(step, train_loss))

  if step % eval_interval == 0:
    avg_return = compute_avg_return(eval_env, agent.policy, num_eval_episodes)
    print('step = {0}: Average Return = {1}'.format(step, avg_return))
    returns.append(avg_return)
```

Comment: It might be due to the environments being different although I am not entirely sure. The collect step method is carried out using train_env whereas the evaluation step is carried out in the eval_env.